# Upload and image with Swift 3 to Parse Server failing: "JSON text did not start with array or object"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform, swift3

I'm trying to upload an image to Parse Server and I'm getting the following output:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 
"JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." 
UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

I tried to upload files of different sizes and I think it's not a problem of size or server limitations. I also tried to declare the variable **imageFile** like this but it shows the same message again:

```
let imageFile = PFFile(data:imageData!, contentType: "image/png")
```

If I upload directly a file from Parse Dasboard UI, it works good and I can retrieve it. Then I'm quite sure it's not a server issue.

***Environment:***

**Swift:** 3

**Parse Version:** 2.3.1

Mounted with Docker + Docker Dashboard.

**Upload Method:**

```
@IBAction func saveBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(profilePic.image!)
    print(imageData!)
    let imageFile = PFFile(name:"avatar.png", data:imageData!)
    print(imageFile!)


    imageFile?.saveInBackground { (result, error) in
        if let error = error{
            print(error)
        }else{
            let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
            query.whereKey("username", equalTo: (PFUser.current()?.username)!)
            query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
                if let user = objects {
                    for object in user {
                        object["name"] = self.nameFld.text
                        object["lastname"] = self.lastnameFld.text
                        object["username"] = self.emailFld.text
                        object["email"] = self.emailFld.text
                        object["avatar"] = imageFile

                        print(object)
                        object.saveInBackground()
                    }
                }
            })

        }
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
1596088 bytes
<PFFile: 0x60000044db30>
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

Comment: Proper strict `JSON` requires either array(`[]`) or object(`{}`) on the top level.  Other values are invalid. Can you get `raw response` and add it to the question?

Comment: @user28434 how i get this raw response? i'm not sure you are trying to achieve..

Comment: It can be done using `PFFile` object. I believe [this Parse guide](http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/ios/guide/#files) on will help you. You can also refer to this [sample code](http://shrikar.com/creating-a-post-and-uploading-image-to-parse/). Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    let currentUser = PFUser.current()!
    currentUser["name"] = self.nameFld.text
    currentUser["lastname"] = self.lastnameFld.text
    currentUser["username"] = self.emailFld.text
    currentUser["email"] = self.emailFld.text

    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(profilePic.image!)
    let imageFile = PFFile(name:"avatar.png", data:imageData!)


      currentUser["avatar"] = imageFile


    // Saving block
    currentUser.saveInBackground { (success, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
                // add action
        } else {
                // add action
        }
    }
```